# Using a file to input variables in csh scripting

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csh

```
unix%:~/tmp$ cat tmp.txt 
z=0.016728
NH=5.7E20
Center for spectra: 2:00:14.906, +31:25:45.826
```

I would like for the value of `z` to be set to a variable named `$redsh`, the value of `NH` to be `$abun`, and the values for the center to be `$xc` and `$yc` respectively.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I’d use `sed` to replace the values from the file, add `set` and run `eval` on the whole thing:

```sh
eval `sed 's/z=/set redsh=/;s/NH=/abun=/;s/.*: \(.*\), \(.*\)/xc=\1 yc=\2/' tmp.txt`
```

#### Example run

```sh
% unset redsh abun xc yc
% cat tmp.txt
z=0.016728
NH=5.7E20
Center for spectra: 2:00:14.906, +31:25:45.826
% eval `sed 's/z=/set redsh=/;s/NH=/abun=/;s/.*: \(.*\), \(.*\)/xc=\1 yc=\2/' tmp.txt`
% set
abun    5.7E20
…
redsh   0.016728
…
xc      2:00:14.906
yc      +31:25:45.826
```

Note however that: [You shouldn't use the C shell. Use the Bourne shell.](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html)

Answer (score 1):

Read `man csh;man grep;man cut;man awk;man tr` and do something like

```
set redsh = "`grep -E '^z=' tmp.txt | cut -d= -f2`"
set abun = "`grep -E '^NH=' tmp.txt | cut -d= -f2`"
set xc = "`grep -E '^Center for spectra: ' tmp.txt | cut -d, -f1 | cut '-d ' -f4`"
set yc = "`grep -E '^Center for spectra: ' tmp.txt | cut -d, -f2 | tr -d ' '`"
```